exams:::exams2pdf: compile SVG and PNG images conditionally
This question regards finding a way to use the same R/exams exercise to pick either an SVG image if exams2html is called, or a twin PNG image if exams2pdf is called.
I have been using SVG images with exams2html because vectorized images look great on any browser. But of course that won't work for exams2pdf so I also export the image to PNG. The images are perfectly identical. Ideally, it would be great if I could code the exercise such that ![](myplot.png){width="40%"} is picked up by exams2pdf and ![](myplot.svg){width="40%"} is picked up by exams2html. Could someone suggest a coding trick inside the exercise to make this happen? Thank you so much.

First, when the graphic is generated in an R figure code chunk within the exercise (e.g., as in boxplots or scatterplot), then you can simply use exams2html(..., svg = TRUE) to get the SVG version while the PNG version would be used by default (also in exams2pdf()).
If you have a static graphic you want to include - or a graphic that you do not generate with a standard figure code chunk - then you can use one of two functions to control which file you use: match_exams_device() or match_exams_call().
With match_exams_device() you get "png" or "svg" etc. depending on which type of graphic a figure code chunk would have used. Thus, you can propagate settings such as exams2html(..., svg = TRUE) into the exercise. Then you could do:
fig <- if(match_exams_device() == "svg") "myplot.svg" else "myplot.png"

and then include it as
![](`r fig`){width="40%"}

With match_exams_call() you can do the same but would check something like:
fig <- if(match_exams_call() %in% c("exams2pdf", "exams2nops")) {
  "myplot.png"
} else {
  "myplot.svg"
}

For further examples see the automaton and logic exercises where the graphics are generated with TikZ using these ideas.

And thank you for the third time, Achim. In my workflow, match_exams_device() does it fully. Many thanks for everything, your accessibility and clarity are amazing. You should allow people donating to r/exams project, I'd surely do it.

You're very welcome. I'm happy if I could help you and if this project I created for managing my own exams is useful for others :-) Please also accept the answer so that it is flagged correspondingly here on SO.
